# PIP install “error: file 'X' does not exist”

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmldiff/0.6.10) via PIP. It gives me the following error:

```
error: file 'c:\users\cai-d\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ncluid\xmldiff\bin\xmldiff.bat' does not exist
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

my OS is Win10 and Here is all the log:

```
λ pip install xmldiff
Collecting xmldiff
Using cached xmldiff-0.6.10.zip
Installing collected packages: xmldiff
Running setup.py install for xmldiff ... error
Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\cai-d\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-teoo7w\\xmldiff\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\cai-d\appdata\local\temp\pip-yq3vmc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\ezs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\fmes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\format.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\input.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\main.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\mydifflib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\objects.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
copying .\__pkginfo__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff
package init file '.\test\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff\test
copying .\test\regrtest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff\test
copying .\test\runtests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff\test
copying .\test\unittest_difflib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff\test
copying .\test\unittest_options.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff\test
copying .\test\unittest_parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff\test
running build_ext
building 'xmldiff.maplookup' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\extensions
C:\Users\Cai-D\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcextensions/maplookup.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\extensions/maplookup.obj
maplookup.c
extensions/maplookup.c(236) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
extensions/maplookup.c(237) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
C:\Users\Cai-D\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:c:\python27\libs /LIBPATH:c:\python27\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:c:\python27\PC\VS9.0\amd64 /EXPORT:initmaplookup build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\extensions/maplookup.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\xmldiff\maplookup.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\extensions\maplookup.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\extensions\maplookup.pyd.manifest
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\extensions\maplookup.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\extensions\maplookup.exp
running build_scripts
creating build\scripts-2.7
error: file 'c:\users\cai-d\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-teoo7w\xmldiff\bin\xmldiff.bat' does not exist

   ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\cai-d\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-teoo7w\\xmldiff\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\cai-d\appdata\local\temp\pip-yq3vmc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\cai-d\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-teoo7w\xmldiff\
```

Comment: are you installing on latest version?

Comment: Do you mean pip? It's the latest version.

Comment: What about python?

Comment: It's Python 2.7.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `ensure_scripts()` in `setup.py` forces extension `.bat` for all scripts, even for scripts written in Python. It's a bug in `setup.py`. Please report it to the authors.

Comment: It is where the problem is. I downloaded the source code and changed file *xmldiff* 's name to *xmldiff.bat*, then the problem is gone. Thank you for your answer sincerely!